# Get error ProgrammingError when insert to MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a dataframe that have about 200M rows with example like this:

```
Date         tableName    attributeName
29/03/2019   tableA       attributeA
....
```

and I want to save the dataframe to a table in MySQL database. This is what I've tried to insert the dataframe to table:

```
def insertToTableDB(tableName,dataFrame):
    mysqlCon = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='')
    cursor = mysqlCon.cursor()
    for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
        myList =[row.Date, row.tableName, row.attributeName]
        query = "INSERT INTO `{0}`(`Date`, `tableName`, `attributeName`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);".format(tableName)
        cursor.execute(query,myList)
        print(myList)
    try:
        mysqlCon.commit()
        cursor.close()        
        print("Done")
        return tableName,dataFrame
    except:
        cursor.close()
        print("Fail")
```

This code successful when I inserted a dataframe that have 2M rows. But, when I inserted dataframe that have 200M rows, I got error like this:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)

ProgrammingError: Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'
```

My dataframe doesn't have 'nan' value. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you print dataFrame.columns

Comment: @tawab_shakeel yes, of course. I already update the question

Comment: put `for` loop in try block or use `if` after `for` loop to check whether all expected  fields are available in dataframe, i think one of your column holding nan (i.e. not a number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these steps

1. drop rows containing nan using `dropna`
2. Filter rows which not contains `nan` in string.
3. Convert nan into None

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df[(df['Date']!='nan') & (df['tableName']!='nan') &(df['attributeName']!='nan')]

df1 = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

Comment: The third one does not work.

Answer (score 2):

replace everywhere 'NaN' for the string 'empty':

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 'empty')
```

Remember to:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: this is not what you want, it should say NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`df = df.astype(str)` solves the problem for me - assuming you've already set up your table schema